# using ruta, annotate a line containing annotation and extract required data

Tags: uima, ruta

Annotate a line containing specific annotations in order to extract text. Annotate line for Borrower and Co-Borrower and get their respective SSNs

```
Borrower Name: Alice Johnson                           SSN: 123-456-7890  
Co-Borrower Name: Bob Symonds                          SSN: 987-654-3210
```

code

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.test;
TYPESYSTEM utils.PlainTextTypeSystem;
ENGINE utils.PlainTextAnnotator;
EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line});
DECLARE Borrower, Name;
DECLARE BorrowerName(String value, String label);
CW{REGEXP("\\bBorrower") -> Borrower} CW{REGEXP("Name") -> Name};
Borrower Name COLON n:CW[1,3]{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};
DECLARE SSN;
DECLARE BorrowerSSN(String label, String value);
W{REGEXP("SSN") -> SSN};
SSN COLON n:NUM[3,3]{-> CREATE(BorrowerSSN, "label"="Borrower SSN", "value"=n.ct)};
DECLARE Co;
CW{REGEXP("Co") -> Co};
DECLARE CoBorrowerName(String label, String value);
Co Borrower Name COLON n:CW[1,3]{-> CREATE(CoBorrowerName, "label"="Co-Borrower Name", "value"=n.ct)};
DECLARE BorrowerLine;
Line{CONTAINS(Borrower),CONTAINS(Name)->MARK(BorrowerLine)};
```

Please suggest how to annotate a line containing annotation and get specific label value for required annotation.

Answer (score 0):

To spare yourself from handling the separate strings, you could gather all the indicators to a wordlist (i.e., a text file containing one indicator per line) and place it in your project *resources* folder (see [this](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#d5e2569) for more details). Then you could just mark all the indicators with the desired indicator type:

```
WORDLIST IndicatorList ='IndicatorList.txt';
DECLARE Indicator;
Document{->MARKFAST(Indicator, IndicatorList )};
```

This would output `Indicator` helper annotations like "Borrower Name".

Once you have that, you could now iterate over the lines and find the target annotations.

```
DECLARE Invisible;
SPECIAL{-PARTOF(Invisible), REGEXP("[-]")-> Invisible};
BLOCK(line) Line{CONTAINS(Indicator)}{

    //Ex. pattern: Borrower Name: Alice Johnson         SSN: 123-456-7890
    Indicator COLON c:CW[1,3]{-> CREATE(BorrowerName, "label"="Borrower Name", "value"=c.ct)} Indicator;
    FILTERTYPE(Invisible);
    Indicator COLON n:NUM[3,3]{-> CREATE(BorrowerSSN, "label"="BorrowerSSN", "value"=n.ct)};
    REMOVEFILTERTYPE(Invisible);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Line{CONTAINS(Indicator)}` returns false. Not going inside block. IndicatorList.txt contains following `Borrower Name
Co-Borrower Name
SSN` each indicator per line

Comment: after trimming WS as @peter suggested, it works. But how to distinctly get BorrowerSSN, right now it fetches both Borrower as well as CoBorrowerSSN? Can we somehow put conditional checks to get respective SSNs?

Comment: You may want to have two separate lists of indicators: one for "Borrower" and another one for "Co-Borrower". Once you have this distinction, you could use a similar rule to the one above to create a `CoBorrowerSSN`. Another (not so elegant) option would be to check the `Indicator` annotation for containing string "Co": `Indicator{REGEXP("\\bCo-[a-zA-Z]+")}` and make a distrinction based on that.

Comment: just a clarification `Line{CONTAINS(Indicator)`, it means iterate over all the lines and  check if any of words mentioned in indicator list is present in that line?

Comment: Correct. That's why you might want to have a distinction between different indicators.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Viorel's answer:

The `PlainTextAnnotator` creates annotations of the type `Line` and these annotation cover the complete line, which means that leading or trailing whitespaces are also included. As a consequence, the resulting annotations are not visible for the following rules. In order to avoid this problem, you could for example trim the whitespaces in these annotations:

```
EXEC(PlainTextAnnotator, {Line});
ADDRETAINTYPE(WS);
Line{-> TRIM(WS)};
REMOVERETAINTYPE(WS);
```